# Display a div if another div is hovered using Jquery

Tags: jquery, css

how to display a `div` inside a `div` if hovered?, I'm trying to do this but there's something wrong, nothing appear.

**code:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 var num = 0;
 $("#add").click(function() {
  $("main").append('<div class="card" id="photo' + num.toString() + '" style="width: 20rem;">\
     <div class="layer"></div>\
     <div class="card-block">\
     <h4 class="card-title" id="title' + num.toString() + '"></h4>\
     <p class="card-text" id="text' + num.toString() + '"></p>\
     </div>\
     <div class="card-block">\
         <div class="delete">Del<div>\
         <div class="edit">edit<div>\
     </div>\
     </div>');

 $(".card").hover(function() {
     $(this > ".delete").css("display", "block");
     $(this > ".edit").css("display", "block");
 });
```

**css**

```
.delete {
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    background-color: red;
    border-radius: 50%;
    position: relative;
    top: 40px;
    left: 120%;
    display: none;
}
.edit {
    width: 35px;
    height: 35px;
    background-color: green;
    border-radius: 50%;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 24px;
    right: 40px;
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: I can see what you meant by `$(this > ".delete")` but what you should have used is: `$(this).children('.delete')`. And that's only if you choose - for unknown reasons - not to use CSS, as [@soilovecuu suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45108123/82548).

Comment: For reference, see [contextual selector](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery-selector-context).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why don't you use css like this:

```
<style>
    .card:hover .delete{
         display:block;
      }
    .card:hover .edit{
         display:block;
      }
</style>
```

Comment: Good point. I think `.card:hover .delete, .card:hover .edit` or maybe `.card:hover .card-block div`.

Comment: Wow, I thought that if I do this,  `delete` and `edit` will be displayed on all cards but it was much easier.Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You're JavaScript is a little wrong.

I am saving the new `div` into its only element so we can add the `hover` event to it specifically. Previously, I think you were likely adding a new hover event to *all* `.card`s. You'd end up with multiple events firing needlessly.

You're `$().css()` lines were incorrect as well. The code below is saying "change the CSS of .delete and .edit nested inside `this`".

```
$(".delete", this).css("display", "block");
$(".edit", this).css("display", "block");
```

You also need to increment `num` after each iteration so you're `.card`s don't have duplicate IDs.

Edit: soilovecuu's answer is probably better. But I'm going to leave this up to show the correct JavaScript.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var num = 0;
  $("#add").click(function() {
    let $div = $('<div class="card" id="photo' + num.toString() + '" style="width: 20rem;">\
     <div class="layer"></div>\
     <div class="card-block">\
     <h4 class="card-title" id="title' + num.toString() + '"></h4>\
     <p class="card-text" id="text' + num.toString() + '"></p>\
     </div>\
     <div class="card-block">\
         <div class="delete">Del</div>\
         <div class="edit">edit</div>\
     </div>\
     </div>');

    num += 1;

    $("main").append($div);

    $div.on('mouseenter', function() {
      console.log('mouseenter');
      $(".delete", this).css("display", "block");
      $(".edit", this).css("display", "block");
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.card {
  background: grey;
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
}

.delete {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: red;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: relative;
  top: 40px;
  left: 120%;
  display: none;
}

.edit {
  width: 35px;
  height: 35px;
  background-color: green;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 24px;
  right: 40px;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" id="add">
  Add
</button>

<main></main>
```

Comment: Also note that the `.edit` and `.delete` elements are missing slashes in their closing tags: `</div>`

Answer (score 1):

Agree with @soilovecuu, this could be easily done (and probably should) with CSS.

However, in sticking with Javascript and Jquery: similar to @rideron89, the javascript (and HTML) is off. I've made some changes (and taken some liberties) to the JS. The primary difference from the other answer is consolidating the event listeners. You could attach one listener to the `main` element using `.card` as the selector parameter. This will essentially listen for any future card elements.

Also, added `mouseleave`.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var num = 0;
  
  $("main").on('mouseover mouseleave', '.card', function(e) {
    var d = e.type === 'mouseover' ? 'block' : '';
    $(".buttons", this).css("display", d);
  });
  
  $("#add").click(function() {
    num++
    $("main").append('<div class="card" id="photo' + num.toString() + '" style="width: 20rem;">\
      <div class="layer"></div>\
      <div class="card-block">\
        <h4 class="card-title" id="title' + num.toString() + '"></h4>\
        <p class="card-text" id="text' + num.toString() + '"></p>\
      </div>\
      <div class="card-block buttons">\
         <div class="delete">Del</div>\
         <div class="edit">edit</div>\
      </div>\
    </div>');
  });
 });
```

```css
.card {
  display:block;
  padding:10px;
  background: #eee;
  margin: 2px;
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
}
.buttons {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  display: none;
}
.delete {
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    background-color: red;
    border-radius: 50%;
    display: inline-block;
}
.edit {
    width: 35px;
    height: 35px;
    background-color: green;
    border-radius: 50%;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<main id="main"></main>
<button id="add">Add</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You had a few syntax errors. Please see below. Also, I took advantage of template literals to help with your multi-line string interpolation.

I couldn't tell if you actually wanted the slashes on the page or not, so I put them in there in case. You can easily remove all of the "\" if you want.

Finally, note that no content (besides the slashes) is being rendered to the page. That's because of two things.

1. Your delete and edit classes have `display: none`
2. You don't have any content in any of the other divs

I'm assuming you did these on purpose, but if not you can correct 1 & 2 and you will get content on the page.

HTML

```
<div id="main">
    <div id="add">Click Me</div>
</div>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var num = 0;
    $("#add").click(function() {
    //"main" should be "#main" assuming there is a div called "main"
    //changed "'" to "`" for multiline strings
    $("#main").append(`
        <div class="card" id="photo${num.toString()}" style="width: 20rem;">\\
        <div class="layer"></div>\\
        <div class="card-block">\\
        <h4 class="card-title" id="title${num.toString()}"></h4>\\
        <p class="card-text" id="text' + num.toString() + '"></p>\\
        </div>\\
        <div class="card-block">\\
        <div class="delete">Del<div>\\
        <div class="edit">edit<div>\\
        </div>\\
        </div>`);

    }); // closing brackets were missing

    $(".card").hover(function() { // moved this inside ready function
    $(this > ".delete").css("display", "block");
    $(this > ".edit").css("display", "block");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this code**

Use this jquery and css to `div hover`

1. This will helps you to hover the `delete` and `edit` div.

### Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){        
var num = 0;
     $("#add").click(function() {
      $("main").append('<div class="card" id="photo' + num.toString() + '" style="width: 20rem;">\
         <div class="layer"></div>\
         <div class="card-block">\
         <h4 class="card-title" id="title' + num.toString() + '"></h4>\
         <p class="card-text" id="text' + num.toString() + '"></p>\
         </div>\
         <div class="card-block">\
             <div class="delete">Del<div>\
             <div class="edit">edit<div>\
         </div>\
         </div>');
        $(".card").hover(function() {
         $(".delete").addClass('delete_pop');
         $(".edit").addClass('edit_pop');});
});
```

### CSS

```
.delete {
width: 30px;
height: 30px;
background-color: #000;
border-radius: 50%;
position: relative;
top: 40px;
left: 120%;
color: #fff;
display: none;}


.edit {
width: 35px;
height: 35px;
background-color: #000;
border-radius: 50%;
position: relative;
bottom: 24px;
right: 40px;
display: none;}



.card{
height: 100px;
width: 100px;
background: red;}

.delete_pop{
display: block;
width: 30px;
height: 30px;
border-radius: 50%;
position: relative;
top: 40px;
left: 120%;
color: #fff;
background-color: yellow;
transition: scale(1.3)(0.8);}

.edit_pop{
width: 35px;
height: 35px;
border-radius: 50%;
position: relative;
bottom: 24px;
right: 40px;
display: block;
background-color: green;
transition: scale(1.3)(0.8);}
```